# Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome_fix3 is not defined _cmp_execLogic._cmp_suclick

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error. How can I resolve this?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome_fix3 is not defined
>   _cmp_execLogic._cmp_suclick

Comment: You may need to provide more context, about what you were doing to cause this error. Perhaps add your code to your question.

Comment: You can check some of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+Uncaught+ReferenceError), answers in them all tell you, why this error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Good news - the error is nothing to do with your site.

Bad news - it's caused by an erroneous browser extension that's injecting invalid javascript into your pages. I have an ever increasing list of similarly caused errors that we can do nothing other than trap and ignore. At some point I intend to feed a message back to the user that something they have installed may cause problems on our sites, but ideally I'd like to tell them exactly what extension is causing the issue, which I don't know in all cases.

If anyone knows where the attempt to reference "chrome_fix3" actually comes from, please add to this post.

A similar error that we trap but is nothing to do with our code is:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: conduitPage is not defined**

I found the following pages helpful when investigating the error:

https://webmademovies.lighthouseapp.com/projects/65733/tickets/2895-crash-referenceerror-conduitpage-is-not-defined

http://www.youtube.com/user/conduityoursite#g/c/4B820DE13E03888D

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to refer to a variable or property that does not exist, in your case it's named chrome_fix3.

This probably came from a javascript libary that you are using, maybe jQuery or something.

I assume that the library is fine and it's caused by wrongfully calling some of it's functions.

The best way now is to install the Firebug plugin in Firefox (you could use Chrome, Opera or Internet Explorer's debugger but I like Firebug best)

Then add following code in your code where you think it's going wrong:

```
//add the following line only once:
var okCounter=0;
// add teh following line every couple of lines in your code:
console.log("still ok here:",okCounter++);
```

Open your page in Forefox and hit F12, the Firebug window should show up now. Reload the page and check out the console tab.

At some point you should notice there is no more output to the console where there should be; now you have found the part in your code where something goes wrong. If you post that part we might be able to help you out more.

Comment: i am not able to change server for my web page. by default it is running on chrome only. can u tall the way to change server.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, server and client browser are not related. I assume you mean Chrome as in Google Chrome. Are you developing user scripts for Chrome? In that case it's Chrome only but you can still use console.log in user scripts I think